# Python | Словарь | Значения | Бесконечный цикл

Tags: python, for, dict

**Good afternoon, dear friend!**

Подскажите, пожалуйста ...

Есть словарь "mas", в нём есть пары: ключ-значение.

С данным кодом у меня получается лишь 3 раза вывести значения.
После 3-го раза, перестаёт читать ключи.
Что необходимо добавить, чтобы можно было бесконечно запрашивать значения словаря?

*******************************Console code*******************************

```
mas = {
"001" : "Колбаса",
"002" : "Бензин",
"003" : "Генная инженерия",
}

for i in mas:
   print (mas.get (input("Введите Ваш код: ")))
```

Comment: Сделайте бесконечный цикл вместо итерации по трем элементам словаря `while True:` вместо `for i in mas:`, но вообще имело бы смысл добавить некое условие выхода...

Comment: @VTT .......... БОЛЬШОЕ СПАСИБО!!!!!!!!!